# What does shite oke mean?

Tags: subsidiary-verbs

The whole sentence: 威嚇するのはしておけ

Comment: Is it really 「威嚇するのはしておけ」? Does it not contain a typo? Nothing between のは and しておけ? Can you double check the original?

Answer (score 1):

> 威嚇するのはしておけ

This phrase doesn't make sense.

There seems to have been some typo.
It should be like:

(A) 威嚇するならさせておけ
(B) 威嚇するならしておけ
(C) 威嚇するのはやめておけ

"prepared to intimidate" means 威嚇する準備はできている, 威嚇する用意はできている or いつでも威嚇できる